# how to put header (and footer) on title page with correct positioning?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I tried to use `fancyhdr` package  and the result I have with the output is as shown [here](http://screencast.com/t/4BEcq1Md). The screenshot shows the junction between pages (bottom of) 3 and (top of) 4 (both header and footer being the same; with lfoot and lhead being "Lecture 1" and rfoot and rhead being "Handout 1").

As you might notice, both header and footer are placed leftwards (taking the page number along with them).

Also, they do not appear on the title page whereas unlike most other cases, I would like them to be present on it.

> MWE below:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Lecture 1}
\rhead{Handout 1}
\lfoot{Lecture 1}
\rfoot{Handout 1}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 
\title{\ul{Proper positioning of headers and footers}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[4-57]
\end{document}
```

Comment: did you try putting `geometry` package before `fancyhdr`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In order to get `fancyhdr` to obey your `geometry` settings you need to call `geometry` first.

And to get the title page to use the same style as the rest, use `\thispagestyle` after `\maketitle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Lecture 1}
\rhead{Handout 1}
\lfoot{Lecture 1}
\rfoot{Handout 1}
%\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
%\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 
\title{Proper positioning of headers and footers}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[4-57]
\end{document}
```

I used `1in` margins because `0.5in` is just too small.  I also added `a4paper` but you can ignore that if you use another size. The top of the output looks like this:

[image]

Normally you use `\thispagestyle` to change the page style temporarily, so for example you might want to change to `plain` or `empty` for certain pages later in the document, but here I've made a temporary change to override the page style that's set by `\maketitle`.  Note that the page style in force at the end of the page is the one used (since the headers and footers are added by the output routine when it ships out a page).