# Headers not showing up on first page when using onecolabstract

Tags: header-footer, abstract

```
\documentclass [10pt, a4paper, twocolumn] {article}

\usepackage {abstract}
\usepackage {fancyhdr}

\pagestyle {fancy}
\lhead {Left}

\renewcommand {\abstractname}{}
\renewcommand {\absnamepos} {empty}

\begin {document}

\title {Title}

\twocolumn[
    \maketitle
    \begin {onecolabstract}
Abstract
    \end {onecolabstract}
    ]

\newpage

\section {}
Section

\newpage

\end {document}
```

Comment: I think they simply don't show up on the title page.

Comment: @AML sorry to ask then, how i can make the headers appear on the title page?

Comment: I think this answer is relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196669/121944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make headers appear on the title page, simply add `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after `\maketitle`. In your case, it will look like this:

```
\twocolumn[
    \maketitle
        \thispagestyle{fancy} %add this
    \begin {onecolabstract}
Abstract
    \end {onecolabstract}
    ]
```

Reference for my answer found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196669/121944).